# Unable to Set AD Attributes using Set-ADUser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, powershell-4.0

I need to change multiple AD Attributes value as per: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/recipient-type-values/7c2620e5-9870-48ba-b5c2-7772c739c651

Therefore I have created this simple script snippet below:

```
$properties = 'Name,sAMAccountName,msExchRemoteRecipientType,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,proxyAddresses' -split ','
$ADUserAttributesValues = Get-ADUser -identity $Input -Properties $properties |
                            Select-Object Name,
                                          msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                                          msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                                          msExchRecipientTypeDetails

# Set The attributes value for Remote Shared Mailboxes
$replace = @{
    msExchRemoteRecipientType = 100
    msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
    msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 34359738368
}
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.sAMAccountName -Replace $replace
```

However, I get this error:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.ToString() -Replace $replace
Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=Domain,DC=com'.
At line:47 char:9
+         Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.ToString() -Repl ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

changing it into **sAMAccountName**

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.sAMAccountName -Replace $replace
Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=Domain,DC=com'.
At line:47 char:9
+         Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.sAMAccountName -Repl ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

also not working either.

Comment: You don't save the `samaccountname` in your variable because you filter the output of `Get-ADUser` with `Select-Object`. Add `SamAccountName` to the properties given through `Select-Object`.

`$ADUserAttributesValues = Get-ADUser -identity $Input -Properties $properties |                            Select-Object Name,msExchRemoteRecipientType,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipient , samaccountname`

Comment: Yes, you are awesome, spot on mate :-) Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. I will wirte a more detailed answer when i got time later on.

Comment: no worries man, you're awesome and spot on :-)